# "is not a member of Any" error from HashMap from Scala JSON reader

Tags: json, scala

I'm open to a different library if you can provide an easy template. I'd prefer a nested map output from my parsed JSON. Thanks!

The relevant code:

```
import scala.util.parsing.json.JSON
...
input = [Some file read in; see bottom for result]
val parsed = JSON.parseFull(input)
val parsedMap = (parsed.toList)(0)
println(parsedMap)
println(parsedMap.getClass())
println(parsedMap.keys)
```

The results, including error at bottom:

> Map(interaction -> Map(author -> Map(name -> iBuyCell, avatar ->
>   http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/1751023331/SellingYourCell1_normal.png,
>   username -> iBuyCell, id -> 4.62459933E8, link ->
>   http://twitter.com/iBuyCell), source -> twitterfeed, id ->
>   1e17bc84c345a800e0742ed998fff162, link ->
>   http://twitter.com/iBuyCell/statuses/186347162957918208, content ->
>   Phone ban presents challenge for police: Chapel Hill became the only
>   town in the state and nation last week to p... http://t.co/xVCQMDU7,
>   created_at -> Sun, 01 Apr 2012 07:00:00 +0000, type -> twitter), links
>   -> Map(created_at -> List(Sun, 01 Apr 2012 04:22:36 +0000), retweet_count -> List(3.0), title -> List(Phone ban presents challenge
>   for police - Orange County - NewsObserver.com), url ->
>   List(http://www.newsobserver.com/2012/04/01/1970433/police-challenged-by-cell-phone.html)),
>   salience -> Map(content -> Map(sentiment -> -1.0)), language ->
>   Map(tag -> en), raw_links -> List(http://bit.ly/HwmJa6), twitter ->
>   Map(source -> twitterfeed, domains -> List(bit.ly), text -> Phone
>   ban presents challenge for police: Chapel Hill became the only town in
>   the state and nation last week to p... http://t.co/xVCQMDU7, links ->
>   List(http://bit.ly/HwmJa6), id -> 186347162957918208, created_at ->
>   Sun, 01 Apr 2012 07:00:00 +0000, user -> Map(utc_offset -> -14400.0,
>   name -> iBuyCell, screen_name -> iBuyCell, location -> Text (Bez) Buy
>   Kyts, url -> http://way.to/FreeFones, description -> Need Cash FAST?
>   Text us 24Hrs For a Quick Quote! In The Mean Time, If You Need a New
>   FREE Cell Phone, With Choice Of Carrier & Style, Click on Website
>   Below!, id_str -> 462459933, listed_count -> 1.0, followers_count ->
>   178.0, id -> 4.62459933E8, created_at -> Thu, 12 Jan 2012 23:58:34 +0000, lang -> en, time_zone -> Atlantic Time (Canada), statuses_count -> 13069.0)))
>
> class scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap
>
> error: value keys is not a member of Any
>   println(parsedMap.keys)

If it helps, here's the original JSON in question:

> {"interaction":{"author":{"avatar":"http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/1751023331/SellingYourCell1_normal.png","id":462459933,"link":"http://twitter.com/iBuyCell","name":"iBuyCell","username":"iBuyCell"},"content":"Phone
>   ban presents challenge for police: Chapel Hill became the only town in
>   the state and nation last week to p...
>   http://t.co/xVCQMDU7","created_at":"Sun, 01 Apr 2012 07:00:00
>   +0000","id":"1e17bc84c345a800e0742ed998fff162","link":"http://twitter.com/iBuyCell/statuses/186347162957918208","source":"twitterfeed","type":"twitter"},"language":{"tag":"en"},"links":{"created_at":["Sun,
>   01 Apr 2012 04:22:36 +0000"],"retweet_count":[3],"title":["Phone ban
>   presents challenge for police - Orange County -
>   NewsObserver.com"],"url":["http://www.newsobserver.com/2012/04/01/1970433/police-challenged-by-cell-phone.html"]},"raw_links":["http://bit.ly/HwmJa6"],"salience":{"content":{"sentiment":-1}},"twitter":{"created_at":"Sun,
>   01 Apr 2012 07:00:00
>   +0000","domains":["bit.ly"],"id":"186347162957918208","links":["http://bit.ly/HwmJa6"],"source":"twitterfeed</a>","text":"Phone ban presents
>   challenge for police: Chapel Hill became the only town in the state
>   and nation last week to p...
>   http://t.co/xVCQMDU7","user":{"created_at":"Thu, 12 Jan 2012
>   23:58:34 +0000","description":"Need Cash FAST? Text us 24Hrs For a
>   Quick Quote! In The Mean Time, If You Need a New FREE Cell Phone, With
>   Choice Of Carrier & Style, Click on Website
>   Below!","followers_count":178,"id":462459933,"id_str":"462459933","lang":"en","listed_count":1,"location":"Text
>   (Bez) Buy
>   Kyts","name":"iBuyCell","screen_name":"iBuyCell","statuses_count":13069,"time_zone":"Atlantic
>   Time
>   (Canada)","url":"http://way.to/FreeFones","utc_offset":-14400}}}

Comment: Have you tried `val parsedMap = (parsed.toList)(0).asInstanceOf[collection.immutable.HashMap[_,_]]`?

Comment: I've heard nothing good about scala's native json parser. What version of scala are you using? See this answer for several alternatives. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12591457/scala-2-10-json-serialization-and-deserialization

Answer (score 0):

[The docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.parsing.json.JSON%24) say that `parseFull` returns an `Option[Any]` that holds either an `Array[Any]` or a `Map[String, Any]`. If you are sure you are parsing a JSON object and not an array, one way to do it would be:

```
JSON.parseFull(input).get match {
  case map: Map[String, Any] => {
    // do anything you have to do with the map here, e.g.:
    println(map.keys)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied your sample JSON and used it to initialize a `String` which I then passed to `scala.util.parsing.json.JSON.parseFull`. The result is an `Option[Any]`, as advertised. You then use `toList` on that `Option[Any]` (which is in fact a `Some` in this case) and get a one-element `List[Any]` (were it a `None`, you'd get an empty `List`). You then select the first (and only) element of that `List`, yielding an `Any`.

At this point, with an `Any` in hand (which could be anything, duh...) you have the ability to invoke only those methods defined on type `Any`. Naturally that does not include `keys`!

One way you can proceed through this is with pattern matching, as Martin Blech illustrates. This kind of a `case` clause effectively combines an `isInstanceOf[Type]` (type test) and an `asInstanceOf[Type]` (cast) giving you a value that statically bears the type `Map[String, Any]`. That that point, you use methods like `keys` or `keySet` (and all the others defined for `Map`).

Lastly note that you'll get an unchecked type warning for that `case` since the value in question is indistinguishable from all other `Map` types, due to the JVM's type erasure.

Comment: why does .getclass say it's a hashtriemap?

Comment: @ElliotJans: Because it is. But the compiler doesn't know that. That's why the `match` approach works. It makes run-time type determinations, not static (compile-time) ones.