# JSON deserialization using Jackson in Scala

Tags: json, scala, serialization, jackson

I'm new to Jackson.  I am encountering the following error when using Jackson to deserialize a JSON string if I don't explicitly specify a class type during deserialization:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate abstract type [simple type, class scala.runtime.Nothing$] (need to add/enable type information?)
```

Is there a way to serialize / deserialize JSON in Jackson without having to specify the class type?

Here is my test code:

```
import java.lang.reflect.{Type, ParameterizedType}
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.`type`.TypeReference;
import org.junit._
import org.junit.Assert._

case class Person (name:String)
case class Address (city:String, state:String)

class JSONTest {

  @Test
  def jsonTest () = {

    val p = new Person ("Bob")

    val json = JacksonWrapper.serialize(p)
    println ("json= " + json)
    val obj = JacksonWrapper.deserialize[Person](json)
    println ("obj = " + obj)

    // fails since class type isn't explictly specified.  
    // is there a way to do it so that class type is automatically determined?
    val obj2 = JacksonWrapper.deserialize(json)
    println ("obj= " + obj2)


  }



}

//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12591457/scala-2-10-json-serialization-and-deserialization
object JacksonWrapper {
  val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
  mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)

  def serialize(value: Any): String = {
    import java.io.StringWriter
    val writer = new StringWriter()
    mapper.writeValue(writer, value)
    writer.toString
  }

  def deserialize[T: Manifest](value: String) : T =
    mapper.readValue(value, typeReference[T])

  private [this] def typeReference[T: Manifest] = new TypeReference[T] {
    override def getType = typeFromManifest(manifest[T])
  }

  private [this] def typeFromManifest(m: Manifest[_]): Type = {
    if (m.typeArguments.isEmpty) { m.erasure }
    else new ParameterizedType {
      def getRawType = m.erasure
      def getActualTypeArguments = m.typeArguments.map(typeFromManifest).toArray
      def getOwnerType = null
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide the type information somehow. Jackson serializes to JSON only your object's fields, it doesn't store additional information about the type anywhere, so for your `Person` class, the JSON probably looks like this: `{ "name": "Bob"}`. Without you providing the information that you want to deserialize as an instance of `Person`, Jackson can't known the type. You could have another class with the field `name` as well, and JSON doesn't say which one you need. That's why you need to provide the type when deserializing - in Java by passing an argument of type `Class` and in Scala by providing the type parameter to `ObjectMapper` and friends.