# java.lang.ClassCastException:ObjectName$$anon$1 cannot be cast to com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.ScalaObjectMapper

Tags: scala, jackson

I am using: `<jackson.version>2.11.2</jackson.version>`
and `<scala.version>2.11.12</scala.version>`

pom file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-module-scala_${scala.version.major}</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I am having the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sample.ObjectName$$anon$1 cannot be cast to com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.ScalaObjectMapper
at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.ScalaObjectMapper$class.$init$(ScalaObjectMapper.scala:338)
at com.sample.ObjectName$$anon$1.<init>(ObjectName.scala:22)
```

at this line(updated import statements below for more info):

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper
val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
def toMap[V](json:String)(implicit m: Manifest[V]): Map[String, Any] = fromJson[Map[String,Any]](json)
def fromJson[T](json: String)(implicit m : Manifest[T]): T = {
    mapper.readValue[T](json)
}
def toJson(value: Any): String = {
    mapper.writeValueAsString(value)
}
```

Anyone else faced the same issue? Any suggestions for the same?

Comment: 2 comments: 1. You dont need to import `jackson-databind`, `jackson-annotations`, and `jackson-core` as they are dependencies of jackson-module-scala. You can see that here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-scala_2.13/2.11.2 . 2. Can you please share your imports? I don't get the same exception. Which scala version are you using?

Comment: updated scala version and imports above

Comment: Are you still getting the same errors?

Comment: yes, i am running in spark streaming job, its probably some serialization issue, but not sure why or how to fix this in jackson xml

Comment: this solution finally worked to implement serialization this way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12591457/scala-2-10-json-serialization-and-deserialization